# How to get the scroll velocity in on Scroll method of android?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener, touch-event

I want to calculate the velocity of scroll when user scrolls on view. I know that onFling method gives the velocity but i want to know the velocity in onScroll method.

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
private OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new OnScrollListener() {

    private int previousFirstVisibleItem = 0;
    private long previousEventTime = 0;
    private double speed = 0;
    
    
    @Override
    public void onScroll(HtcAbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (previousFirstVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem){
            long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeToScrollOneElement = currTime - previousEventTime;
            speed = ((double)1/timeToScrollOneElement)*1000;

            previousFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            previousEventTime = currTime;

            Toast.makeText(Screen_SubjectsLibrary.this, "Speed: " +speed + " elements/second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(HtcAbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not using any (ViewGroup) recyclerView etc  for scroll. I am using (View)PlayerView to scroll i.e. video is forwarded or rewind when user scrolls on it. And i want to get the speed of scroll.